# Если экспортировать проект в эклипсе в исполняемый джар файл, он будет у всех работать?

Tags: java

Если экспортировать проект в эклипсе в исполняемый джар файл, он будет у всех работать?

Comment: Это не экспортирование проекта. Перефразируйте ваш вопрос и уточните детали проекта

Answer (score 1):

При использовании функции `File -> Export -> Runnable JAR File` полученый jar файл будет работать на любой системе, на которой установлен JRE той версии, которая указана как target версия в настройках проекта.

Все необходимые зависимости либо внедряются в сам jar-файл либо копируются в отдельную папку, в зависимости от того, какие опции будут выбраны при экспорте.